# Using Google JavaScript based StreetView in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, uiwebview

I'm trying to implement a sort of Google street view on a UIWebView. I have a map with annotations, and when you tap on the disclosure for the annotation a new scene is pushed.

Inside that scene is just my UIWebView and a tool bar with a close button.

I'm loading a local file which renders the Google Maps street view via the JavaScript API. [Here is the source code](http://pastebin.com/fkuqfLXy).

I then evaluate some JS to reposition the panoramic view to be the location of the user.

My view gets memory warnings very quickly as you scroll in a 360 view. I'm not doing a lot of tapping, just a panoramic view of the location I'm in.

Sometimes the view dies, and other occasions the app crashes all together.

```
2011-01-31 22:46:20.262 iPadApp[2151:307] Received memory warning. Level=1
2011-01-31 22:46:35.551 iPadApp[2151:307] Received memory warning. Level=1
2011-01-31 22:46:50.651 iPadApp[2151:307] Received memory warning. Level=1
```

It seems to consume a lot of memory when you do the double tap to zoom. I looked at ways to suppress the double tap in the Google options, and by subclassing UIWebView, so that only single taps get through.

Strangely, I can bring up the same file in mobile safari and it handles the memory management fine and doesn't crash.

It would make my life a whole lot easier if Apple opened up their API so developers could use the street view in MapKit.

Does anyone know how I can achieve what I'm attempting without it crashing all the time? Or is there a better way to achieve a street view in iOS?

Comment: Have you seen the Trip Advisor iPad app? I believe they are doing what you are attempting to do, though I think they've heavily modified how street view works. A few observations, they restricted your movement to only allow you to turn left and right and not up and down, another thing I noticed is that the frame rate seems a lot choppier than the street view in the maps app. I can only imagine what trickery the boys at Trip Advisor are doing but it might be worth a try, to at least email them and ask.

Comment: Never mind you seemed to have fixed your problem.

Comment: check my answer in here -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913885/how-to-open-google-street-view-in-uiwebview/39415051#39415051

Comment: Check my answer in here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913885/how-to-open-google-street-view-in-uiwebview/39415051#39415051

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the webview on a popover view controller this works, presumably because the view is smaller and smaller images are shown.